# fullCalendar with gCal showing a second, blank calendar

Tags: jquery, html, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

I have a google calendar successfully rendering with fullCalendar, but for some reason I'm getting two calendars rendering inside my #trainingCalendar div: one blank one at the top of the page and a second, correct (google calendar linked with clickable events displayed) one below. Here's the html, even though it's really simple:

```
<body>
    <div id="training">  //more stuff will go in this div, but I wanted to keep it as simple as possible for troubleshooting
        <div id="trainingCalendar">
        </div>
    </div> 
    <br class="clearfix" />
    <div id="footer">
        &copy; 2012 darkermarkerproductions.com
    </div>
</body>
```

...and here's the page itself: http://www.darkermarkerproductions.com/trainingCalendar.html

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running it twice--once near the top of your *scriptMain.js*, and once near the bottom.
 You need to remove this code:

```
$('#trainingCalendar').fullCalendar({
    // your options here
});
```

from the bottom of *scriptMain.js*.